# how to avoid the member assignment in LINQ orderby/groupby

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have a query to return a count based on a condition

```
 var query = (from a in this.db.Servers    
 where (a.Date >= fromDP.SelectedDate.Value && a.Date <= toDP.SelectedDate.Value)   
 group a by EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a.Date) into p
 select new { b = p.Count()}).OrderBy( x=> x.b);
```

**EDIT**

when binded to a ListBox's ItemSource like this,

```
 dummy.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
```

**XAML**

```
  <ListBox x:Name="dummy"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

which displays the output like this

[image]

how to avoid the member assignment "b" here and display only the integer values? is it possible

Comment: What displays the output? There's nothing in your snippet that displays the output...

Comment: This, in and of itself, doesn't output anything. Are you talking about the debug view?

Comment: I am sorry, I will edit the question now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just guess you should avoid using *anonymous type* in here by *selecting count* directly:

```
var query = (from a in this.db.Servers    
             where (a.Date >= fromDP.SelectedDate.Value 
                           && a.Date <= toDP.SelectedDate.Value)   
             group a by EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a.Date) into p
             select p.Count()).OrderBy(x => x);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing that in debugger *(I guess)*. Since you are selecing an [Anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx) with `new` in select, `b` is the name of the property holding that value.

You can print those values like:

```
foreach(var item in query)
    Console.WriteLine(item.b);
```

With the above code you will get only the values.

**EDIT:** *Since now the question has been edited with ListBox,*

Do not project to Anonymous type. Simply `select p.Count`, so your query would be:

```
var query = (from a in this.db.Servers    
where (a.Date >= fromDP.SelectedDate.Value && a.Date <= toDP.SelectedDate.Value)   
group a by EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a.Date) into p
select p.Count()).OrderBy( x=> x);  //Remove new and b
```

Comment: I don't think this deserves a downvote. It's only a guess, but I suspect it's exactly what the OP is seeing.

Comment: I am sry sir, i forgot to mention Listbox's ItemsSource. how to achieve this in listbox

Comment: I Agree with ken2k. Doesn't deserve a downvote. (@user1221765 Ken2k was talking about the downvote this answer received, not your question)

Comment: yes sir, thank you. this works for me. the previous user has given the same solution as yours

Comment: @user1221765, naah, there is one and that too without reason, would love to hear the reason though :)

Comment: @user1221765 Click on the number at the top left of the answer and it will change to show you the + and - values. But it's been reversed now, so no worries :)

Answer (score 1):

All above solutions are correct but we can set the `DisplayMemberPath` and easily achieve what you want

```
dummy.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
dummy.DisplayMemberPath = "b";
```

[**`DisplayMemberPath`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx)

> Gets or sets a path to a value on the source object to serve as the
>   visual representation of the object.